# Elastic Beanstalk - Customize Nginx configuration files - PHP Web Application

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The beanstalk documentation is not clear on how and what is best way to customize nginx configuration when deploying PHP applications.

I've tried multiple things as include a file **/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-security.conf** like this:

```
files:
/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-security.conf:
mode: “000644”
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always ;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
  add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" 
  always;
  add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
```

I've tried other alternatives but none of them seems to be working. I am a bit confused as beanstalk doesn't give any clear direction on how that should be done for PHP? I've seen people using different strategies, some of them back in 2018, 2017...

I can replace the configuration using container_commands and then restart nginx, but there is any way where I can add more configuration files or modify the original one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible reason why your `/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-security.conf` is  not working, is because you are using **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2). However, the setting file is for old EB platforms based on AL1.

For AL2, the nginx settings should be in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not in `.ebextentions` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Therefore, you could have the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with content:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always ;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" 
always;
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
```

The above is **an example**. I can't verify if the settings will actually work, but it seems to me that you are using AL2, not AL1. In this case, you are ussing wrong folders for the `nginx` config files.